# What sort of view is the Add Event dialog in iPad calendar?

Tags: ipad, uitableview, dialog

It looks like it may be a uitableview with various sorts of cells in it, but how would they have done the pointer (that makes a bit like a MS Word callout) on the side of the frame
?

Answer (score 0):

It is a UITableView nested inside a UIPopoverController.

The UIPopoverController is specific to the iPad.

**Edit after comment by the OP**

In response to the comment by the OP, and, although I know someone will accuse hurling an RTFM... There *is* an illustrated catalog of widgets, complete with a description of when you should use them the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) (or the **HIG**). If your goal is to publish an app in the app store then you really should be familiar with this document.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful - I know where to look now. Shame there isn't an illustrated catalog of widgets telling you what they all are...